# dompdf incompatibilidad con php7

Tags: pdf, php7

!Saludos¡

Estaba trabajando con PHP Versión 5.4.3 y con DOMPDF (para imprimir en un pdf lo del formulario en php); al realizar la actualización a PHP Versión 7.2.1 me arroja el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught DOMPDF_Exception: No block-level parent found. Not good. in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\inline_positioner.cls.php:38 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(546): Inline_Positioner->position() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\text_frame_reflower.cls.php(331): Frame_Decorator->position() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Text_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\page_frame_reflower.cls.php(138): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Page_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\dompdf.cls.php(817): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\Impresion.php(859): DOMPDF->render() #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ctacobro_6\production\dompdf\include\inline_positioner.cls.php on line 38

he aqui el codigo:

```
<?php
$code='aquí va el html'
// se crea una nueva instancia al DOMPDF
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
// se carga el codigo html
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($code));
// aumentamos memoria del servidor si es necesario
ini_set("memory_limit","50M"); 
// lanzamos a render
$dompdf->render();
// guardamos a PDF
$dompdf->stream("PA03-PR04-F02.pdf");
$bd_certsup2->close();
?>
```

Tampoco me funcionan las versiones Dompdf 0.8.1 y Dompdf 0.8.2.

Muchas gracias¡

Comment: El error suele ocurrir cuando la variable que usas, en este caso `$code` es `NULL` o cuando falta alguna librería de tratamiento de HTML. [Ver diferentes soluciones en este hilo](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/902).

Comment: Según yo, el método es `loadHtml` y no `load_html`, prueba cambiando eso y prueba también pasándole una cadena html arbitraria tipo `<div>aqui va el html</div>`

Comment: Hola @amenadiel con el cambio que sugeriste "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DOMPDF::loadhtml() in C..."

Comment: bueno, en la versión actual existe `load_html` pero por dentro invoca a `loadHtml`. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/605cd035970960b5459313992307fd55368c97f7/src/Dompdf.php#L404 pero prueba lo de la cadena arbitraria sin tocar el nombre del método, por si acaso

Comment: @A.Cedano ya intenté lo sugerido en el foro:
1. Remove space between <html><head> , </head><body> and </body></html>
2. After enabling the HTML5 parser
3. Cambiar "$dompdf->load_Html($html)" por "$dompdf->loadHtml($html)"
Sigo buscando...

Answer (score 1):

Es muy extraño, pero de todas las posibles soluciones encontradas en foros y demás páginas, la única que me funcionó fue esta:

Eliminar el espacio en blanco entre los siguientes elementos

```
<html><head>
</head><body>
</body></html>
```

No hay problemas con el espacio en blanco en cualquier otro lugar del archivo.

La solución por:

> @benabbottnz commented on 26 Sep 2017 in https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/389

```
PDT:PHP Version 7.2.1 / DOMPDF 0.6.0 beta 3 release notes
```

¡Saludos!